# Question related to button in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to represent dimensions for layout_width or layout_height in percentage for button in android?? if not is there any alternative so that the effect will be same???

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_width="100dip" and android:layout_height="100dip"`

Answer (score 0):

i believe that the best practice on changing sizes is textAppearance attribute.
the doc about it is in here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAppearance and here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textAppearance

so if you don't really need static size and only want it to be relatively smaller or bigger, you should use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a view to occupy i.e. 30% of parent's space? You can do the trick using linear layout with dummy view occupying 70% of space (it can be done using weights). But best approach is just write your own layout for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you cannot specify size in percentage for any layout. But there is one layout introduced in support library example called **PercentageRelativeLayout**:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Another alternative solution is to use **weightSum** and **layout_weight** attribute for any parent and child layout. An example is shown below. This will work same as percentage and both child layouts will be alloted 50% width on screen.**weightSum is used for parent layout and layout_weight is used for child layout.**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:tileMode="repeat" >
        </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:tileMode="repeat" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```